# How to fix jumping / snapping CSS Hover effect in MS Edge

Tags: css, hover, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

I'm experiencing a weird phenomenon using Microsoft Edge (40.15063.674.0) / Microsoft EdgeHTML (15.15063) with the code below. As expected, when you hover over the black box with any browser, it smoothly scales the box to 1.25x its size over 0.5 seconds. The problem happens when a mouse is moving too fast across the box in Edge. What happens is that instead of scaling smoothly, the box jumps/snaps to the desired transformation and then back again. Let’s say a user was moving their mouse fast from one side of the screen to the other and “cutting across the lawn” so to speak across the surface of the box.

In fact, if I move too fast in other browsers, the box doesn't attempt to scale at all. It just stays small unless the mouse movement actually ends up stopping in that area. Even in Internet Explorer this works just fine with as fast as I can move the mouse pointer across it, but only in Edge do I find this behavior. I have to go relatively slow to prevent that jitter-like snap. It doesn't matter what the effect is either. It could be a "scale", a "translateY", etc. If the mouse is moving too fast across the ":hover" it's not smooth in Edge. Is this a known issue? Is there anything I could do to prevent this from happening?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<style>

    .box {
        background-color: #000;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        left: 200px;
        top: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        width: 200px;
        transition: transform 0.5s;
        transition-delay: 0.1s;   <=== Added this to stop it from jumping
    }

    .box:hover {
        transform: scale(1.25);
    }

</style>

<div class="box"></div>
```

I've even tried replicating the effect using jQuery's ".hover" function to add the CSS attributes when the mouse enters and then take them away when the mouse leaves but to no avail. It behaves exactly the same way. The hover effect jumps/snaps if the mouse is moving too fast in Edge.

Comment: I think it is by design. I have tested your code on Chrome, IE 11 and Microsoft Edge (42.17134.1.0) / Microsoft EdgeHTML (17.17134), if I move too fast, the box doesn't attempt to scale at all. If I move the mouse slowly, it will work well.

Comment: Unless there's been a change in Edge from 40->42, EdgeHTML 15->17, when I move my cursor too fast in my version of Edge, the box jumps immediately to the 1.25x scale without taking 0.5s to do so. It doesn't just not attempt to scale at all, it's like it transforms but without applying the time parameter (as if it were set at 0s).

Answer (score 0):

This should be a comment, but sub-50 rep here.

You might want to try adding translateZ() or use scale3d() directly, to enable hardware acceleration, and using transition-delay to delay the transition altogether when hovering for less than 100ms.

```
.box:hover {
    transform: scale3d(1.25, 1.25, 1.25);
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
/* or */
.box:hover {
    transform: translateZ(0) scale(1.25);
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
}
```

Comment: You could go about the problem like this: it is a browser-specific issue, with a specific scenario where it happens, which is likely something to do with how the browse optimizes the render/paint of these transitions from the 'collapsed' state to the 'expanded' state and back again. It might have very limited real-use-case value. The only other thing i can think of trying is adding a **transition delay** of up to 100ms (which is imperceptible to the user), which would delay the transition itself. Or better yet, use this within an **animation** with said delay.

Comment: HA! BANG! Did not know about "**transition-delay**" within CSS directly. Had tried a similar delay mechanism with jQuery but it didn't work. Thanks for the idea! Have updated the original with this answer.

Comment: Glad it worked. Updated my answer also to reflect this. Best of luck! :)